# Does timer belong to service or broadcast receiver?

Tags: android

We all know what a timer app does, and we also know it runs on background. So my question is, which does it belong to? Does it belong to service or broadcast receiver?

Comment: You talking about standard timer app? I think it work like normal app, have broadcastreceiver and it's run his own service when needed, no?

Comment: So it's a combination of both?

Comment: If you want to track the time, you will have to create a service. When you restart your app, you can listen to a Boot Complete broadcast receiver and restart counting based on the time you started the count. I don't think a broadcast receiver alone is going to solve your problem.

Comment: @GlennMichaelTorregosa Main App work when user want it, service work when timer has started and stop. BroadcastReceiver listen for other apps to work like an API for your app.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to do what you want

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    Timer timer;
    Handler helper;

    public static long TIME = 60000; // Repeats every 1 minute


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        timer = new Timer();
        helper = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                // Actions to be made every 1 minute

            }
        }, 0, TIME);

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        timer.cancel();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```